# How can I change this class component into a functional component?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm trying to transform all my class components to functional components. I'm using redux to handle my state but I'm not yet well conversant with functional components. How can I transform this Class component to a functional component?

```
class PersonnelPage extends Component {
  state = {
    isLoading: false,
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getEmployees();
  }

  handleDeleteEmployee(id) {
    return (e) => this.props.deleteEmployee(id);
  }
  render() {
    const { employees } = this.props;
    return (
      <>
      </>
    );
  }
}

function mapState(state) {
  const employees = state;
  return employees;
}

const actionCreators = {
  getEmployees: employeeActions.getAll,
  deleteEmployee: employeeActions.delete,
};

const connectedPersonnelPage = connect(mapState, actionCreators)(PersonnelPage);
export { connectedPersonnelPage as PersonnelPage };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well, for converting a class based component to a functional component using hooks, for each field in the `this.state` in the class component, you use a `useState` call.

since `componentDidMount` dosent exist in a functional component, you can use `useEffect` which acts as a replacement for both `componentDidMount`, `componentDidUpdate`, and `componentWillUnmount`.

so the component will look something like this

```
function PersonnelPage(props) {
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        props.getEmployees();
    }, [props.getEmployees]);

    const handleDeleteEmployee = id => {
        return e => props.deleteEmployee(id);
    };
    return <></>;
}

function mapState(state) {
    const employees = state;
    return employees;
}

const actionCreators = {
    getEmployees: employeeActions.getAll,
    deleteEmployee: employeeActions.delete,
};

const connectedPersonnelPage = connect(mapState, actionCreators)(PersonnelPage);
export { connectedPersonnelPage as PersonnelPage };
```

Comment: "componentDidUnmount" should be "componentWillUnmount" for useEffect.

Answer (score 1):

Here is functional component for your code:

```
function PersonnelPage({ getEmployees, employees, ...props }) {
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        getEmployees();
    }, [getEmployees]);

    const handleDeleteEmployee = id => {
        return e => props.deleteEmployee(id);
    };
    return <></>;
}

function mapState(state) {
    const employees = state;
    return employees;
}

const actionCreators = {
    getEmployees: employeeActions.getAll,
    deleteEmployee: employeeActions.delete,
};

const connectedPersonnelPage = connect(mapState, actionCreators)(PersonnelPage);
export { connectedPersonnelPage as PersonnelPage };
```